# Make that my website shows an HTML just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm making a html and Javascript app to build with Phonegap, so I have my registration page that I need to be displayed only once, only the first time that the user opens the app. After that, never shows again.

Comment: What if the person doesnt register?

Comment: What is localStorage();

Comment: If the person doesnt register, cant acces the app itself

Comment: Typically, you'd have a login screen that has a link to show the registration form. This way the user can log in if they already have an account and can click the register button if they dont have an account.

Comment: On this app its supposed that after the registration, the login process its automatic, an the user doesn't have to login manually

Comment: @DelightedD0D makes a good point about user viewing app at different device. What is expected result if user views app from a device other than the one where registration occurred?

Comment: Also, *the login process its automatic*, how exactly does that work? What happens if that the logged in state gets corrupted (cleared cache / cookies/ localstorage, etc... whatever keeps track of it)? Is there a way to manually log in if that happens? Or is the user then forced to re-register?

Comment: You made me think about a lot of stuff... thanks, i have to talk with my team and redefine the login and register

Comment: Since you are dealing with a cordova app, I would try to go with device storage rather than volatile html storage API. [This plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage) (untested) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need either cookies or local storage to keep track of the user. I would suggest local storage as it is better than cookies, gives more space to store data and is easier to use.

Consider going through this:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @DelightedD0D you are implying on what OP's use case is. This is a valid answer.

Comment: The data is going to be stored on the server, but also on the device for the offline working

Comment: @DelightedD0D So how do you propose the server automatically knows this? User Accounts are required to do this and it is mentioned that he is building an app using JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that in kind of a hurry in the mobile app. That was meant to be a comment on the question, not your answer.

Comment: This is a cordova app, so while written in javascript and HTML, it is hosted on user's device and is an native app per se.